# Which code performs better in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is related to following code  -

**Scenario 1:**

```
var queue = [];
var busy = false;

exports.getAProfile = function (params, cb) {
    queue.push({params: params, cb: cb});
    if (!busy) {
        checkQueue(function (c, next) {
            service.getAProfileNow(c.params, function (err, res) {
                c.cb(err,res);
                next();
            });
        });
    }
}

function checkQueue(actualTask) {
    var c = queue.shift();
    if (c) {
        busy = true;
        actualTask(c, function () {
            checkQueue(actualTask);
        })
        return queue.length;
    } else {
        busy = false;
        return queue.length;
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
var queue = [];
var busy = false;

var actualTask = function (c, next) {
    service.getAProfileNow(c.params, function (err, res) {
        c.cb(err,res);
        next();
    });
}

exports.getAProfile = function (params, cb) {
    queue.push({params: params, cb: cb});
    if (!busy) {
        checkQueue();
    }
}

function checkQueue() {
    var c = queue.shift();
    if (c) {
        busy = true;
        actualTask(c, function () {
            checkQueue(actualTask);
        })
        return queue.length;
    } else {
        busy = false;
        return queue.length;
    }
}
```

Difference in both codes are -

- The function `actualTask` is (i guess) defined many times in first scenario while in Second scenario it is defined only once.

is 'what I interpret' correct? then which one is better? and why? is performance of code different in both?

Note: `service` module is require-d in code, it only queries database.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: This (and performance tab in browser devtools) might be an useful tool to try it out: https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score -1):

Defining function just once does not make the performance or execution fast. It will just reduce the file size of your code and make your code formation pretty well. In both cases, the function must have to jump to procedure call.

Comment: and this doesn't make any sense